# Stuck while deriving the Lindblad Master Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

I was following *Quantum Markov Processes* from the book *The Theory of Open Quantum Systems* by *Breuer and Petruccione*. In the section *The Markovian Quantum Master Equation* they proceeds to 'construct the most general form for the generator $\mathcal{L}$ of a quantum dynamical semigroup.' Then I observed that almost the same approach is taken in the book *Quantum Dynamical Semigroups and Applications* by *Alicki and Lendi*, so I moved there.
We have the definition of $\mathcal{L}$: $$\frac{d}{dt}\rho_t=\mathcal{L}\rho_t$$ with $\rho_t=\Lambda_t\rho$. And this gives $\Lambda_t=e^{\mathcal{L}t}, t\ge0.$
For unbounded $\mathcal{L}$ they have used the following definition of exponential - $$e^{\mathcal{L}t}\rho=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\mathcal{L}\right)^{-n}\rho.$$ After that,

> We find now a general form of $\mathcal{L}$ in the case of finite-dimensional
> Hilbert space $\mathcal{H_S}$ (dim $\mathcal{H_S} = N$). Introducing a linear basis {$F_k$}, $k =$
> $0,1,... ,N^2 − 1$ in $\mathcal{B(H_S)}$ such that $F_0 = \mathbb{1}$ we may write a
> time-dependent version of $\Lambda\rho=\sum_{\alpha} W_{\alpha}\rho W_{\alpha}^*$ as follows, $$\Lambda_t\rho=\sum_{k,l=0}^{N^2-1}C_{kl}(t)F_k\rho F_l^*,$$ where $C_{kl}(t)$ is a positive-definite matrix.

The part after this is what I'm totally in the dark with. Let me paste the photo as it will be too much effort to type:
[image]

How are we getting this expression for $\mathcal{L}\rho$ with all these limits, $\epsilon$'s and all that? What I got is the following: $$\mathcal{L}\rho=\frac{d}{dt}\rho_t=\frac{d}{dt}{[\Lambda_t\rho]}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{k,l=0}^{N^2-1}C_{kl}(t)F_k\rho F_l^*\right)$$ but can proceed no further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with the notation, $\rho = \rho_0$ is the initial state here. The left hand side of your last equation should be $\mathcal L \rho_t$.

We thus have to evaluate the equation at $t=0$, obtaining
$$ \mathcal L \rho = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( \sum_{kl} C_{kl}(t) F_k \rho F_l^\dagger \Bigr)_{t=0} . $$

The result now follows from
$$ \left. \frac{d}{dt} f(t) \right|_{t=0} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \bigl( f(\epsilon) - f(0) \bigr) , $$
that is, $\mathcal L \rho = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \bigl( \Lambda_\epsilon \rho - \rho \bigr)$.

There is a typo in Alicki / Lendi, the sums in the final result are all supposed to start at $1$ instead of zero. The same calculation can be found for example in the proof of Thm. 5.1 in the [Rivas / Huelga book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5242), I think it is a bit easier to understand there.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.   
Thanks, it makes sense @Noiralef.    
Also, regarding your *edit*, I think you are talking about a typo in the original Alicki & Lendi book, right?    

While proceeding to the final form, I also had to make two guesses, of course without being able to prove:   
1. $C_{kl}(t)|_{t=0}=\mathbb{1}$;        
2. $C_{kl}(t)|_{t=0}=0$, unless $k$ and $l$ are simultaneously zero.               

Any comment on this will be highly valued. Thanks!

Comment: @QuestionTheAnswer These guesses should be correct, but you don't even need that. The $t=0$ terms are $\Lambda_0 \rho$ which is equal to $\rho$ by definition. I have edited my answer a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my doubts!